# Report old advertisements and packages in SCCM 2007

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I would like to find an easy way to list all "old" packages and advertisement.
If I could list them by last date used I would get a good idea of what stuff that could be removed.

Comment: This one shows packages that has no adertisments linked to them. One problem with this is that it will show the absolute newest packages as well.

Select * from 
dbo.v_Package
Where PackageID not in (select Packageid from dbo.v_Advertisemen